# PowerShell error passing a variable in Test-Path command. Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string

Tags: powershell

Below is the code I'm trying to run. I had this work one time before but now it says the string is null. If I pass the entire string path into the command it works, but it will not work with the variable.

```
$BipResPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Application\myapp\bin\myfile.dll"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'myComputer' {Test-Path "$BipResPath"}

Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Test-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestPathCommand
    + PSComputerName        : myComputer
```

I want to see a $true or $false but I can only get that return with I pass the entire path string into the code.

Comment: `{Test-Path $using:BipResPath}` see linked answer